# javascript - part of method called twice

Tags: javascript, methods

I am trying to write a custom, simple heightmap-generation in javascript. So far I got the code down but I experienced something very weird that is blocking my way. I'm not sure if it's a bug or me just being blind. A part of the code is as follows:

```
function fillNeighboursHill(life) {
    //...
    life--;
    neighbours = this.getNeighbours();
    neighbourstring = 'Before:'+neighbours.length+'\n';
    for (var i=0; i < neighbours.length; i++) {
        //do something
        neighbours[i].fillNeighboursHill(life);
    }
    neighbourstring += 'After:'+neighbours.length+'\n';
    alert(neighbourstring);
}
```

This is a function that calls itself recursively for a few times. Though, if you look at the neighbourstring, you would always expect an alert at the end in this pattern:

> Before:8
>   After: 8

This is the case in almost all cases, but sometimes I would get

> Before:8
>   After: 8
>   After: 8

for no understandable reason. For me, that does not make any sense as it would mean that the bottom part of the function is executed twice, though there is nothing to force such behaviour. Am I missing something?

Any tips regarding my problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should try reducing your problem to the smallest possible example that still exhibits the issue. It is hard to determine what is wrong due to the complexity of the code.

Comment: I did not want to ommit part of the code as it might have hidden some usefull information important for debugging. Though, someone was able to help me nonetheless. Thanks for your downvote by the way, it helps me as a first-poster improve. If that downvote was not from you then ignore this comment.

Comment: no, that downvote was not from me. I was trying to help you improve your question. Don't let it discourage you, StackOverflow is a friendly place. You should try reading http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being `neighbours` a global it can happen that between `neighbourstring = 'Before:'+neighbours.length+'\n';` and `neighbourstring += 'After:'+neighbours.length+'\n';` another call of the function is being executed between the two assignments. Declaring it with `var neighbours` should solve it.

Comment: Can't believe it, that has been it. Though, it's funny because neighbours is not a global variable and should therefor only exist in the scope of the function. Thus it's weird that it seems to work most times as expected, but in 1 of 8 cases it doesn't.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually it's a global variable, unless you declare it with var. You can check that `neighbours == window.neighbours` is true after `neighbours = this.getNeighbours();`

Comment: Thank you for clarifieing this to me. I used to program with different languages and expected variable scopes to be the same as in other languages. This knowledge will help me alot.